# перенос строки в textarea jquery

Tags: html, jquery

вот эта строчка вставляет в `textarea` две переменные

```
$('#cabinetregistrationform-company_name1').val(suggestion.data.name.short_with_opf + suggestion.data.management.name);

suggestion.data.name.short_with_opf и suggestion.data.management.name
```

это два текста ,
как между ними сделать перенос строки?
`+ '\n' +` не работает

вывод переменных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если `\r\n` ?

Comment: @UModeL   тоже не работает , syntax error в консоле

Comment: Проверьте, что выводит в консоли `suggestion.data.name.short_with_opf` и `suggestion.data.management.name`.  Отдельно каждый.

Comment: Похоже, что одно из значений = undefined

Comment: @UModeL дополнил ответ, там нет undefined. Все правильно приходит, это название компании и имя ген.дир. из сервиса Dadata

Comment: `#cabinetregistrationform-company_name1` - это `<textarea>`?

Comment: А без переноса нормально всё вставляется?

Comment: @UModeL да в одну строку слеплено

Comment: @UModeL #cabinetregistrationform-company_name1 это textarea да

Comment: Вывод в консоль точно стоит непосредственно перед строчкой из примера?

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю какие у вас проблемы с переносом строки, но управляющая конструкция \r\n встроенная между строк вполне справляется c переносом, как вам и советовали в комментариях

```js
var textarea = $('#cabinetregistrationform-company_name1');
var text1 = 'lorem';
var text2 = 'lorem2';
textarea.val(text1 + '\r\n' + text2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="cabinetregistrationform-company_name1"></textarea>
```

Запустите код, чтобы увидеть результат

Comment: говорю же Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: Значит вы разбиваете строчку в редакторе на несколько строк. Чтобы исправить можно побробовать соеденить строки в es6 стиле с помощью строкового литерала.
```textarea.val(`${text1}\r\n${text2}`);```
Подробнее об этой ошибке можно почитать здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal